# Form button not working in IE11

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

I have created a form with a submit button, the submit button is outside the actual form but its targeting the form using the form attribute for example.

```
<form id="myform">
</form>

<button form="myform"></button>
```

I apologize for the week example. This is working accross all browsers except IE 11. IE 8-10 is working 100%. Any ideas on how I can fix this. I prefer not writing scripts. I can do this with jQuery but I prefer to just keep it clean if possible

Comment: Why don't you use <input type="submit"> inside of form tag? This is not good way to put button outside of form tag.

Comment: The reason for having it outside is to be floated differnly to the form and the container that the form is inside

Comment: [IE documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says: "Retrieves a reference to the form that the object is _embedded in_."

Comment: How does the HTML5 form attribute work in IE 8-9? It does not have support for it.

Comment: That is the anomaly that I could not figure out. That is why I created this post. But I have used @specialone's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with just a click event and a line of css. ( Minimal )

If your button has to be outside the form due to User Interface design.

I would suggest you add an input submit/button inside the form:

```
<form id="myform">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" class="myButton" />
</form>
<button id="outerBtn">Submit</button>
```

Hide the input:

```
.myButton {display:none;} OR {visibility:none;}
```

Use jQuery to trigger click the input button inside the form:

```
$('#outerBtn').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.myButton').trigger('click');
});
```

Just some quick answer. Should be alright.
If you do not want to write script, I would suggest you just keep your input button/submit inside the form.

Comment: This does work perfectly thank you, but is there no way of ignoring the jQuery? Why does this not work on IE 11 specifically, I cant find an explanation anywhere

Comment: @hamed is right, it is not right to put a button outside a form when you want to interact with that form. Yes right now based on your testing IE11 specifically might have issue but I believe if you did more testings on several browsers and operating system you can see that they might also not work. If you want to ignore jQuery, I would suggest you put the correct input button/submit inside the form.

Comment: @Philip please select my post as your answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: @specialone: in html5 it's absolutely right to but a submit button outside a form (with attribute form=<formId>). It just seems that IE/Edge is not playing along.

Comment: If go with Javascript you don't need the second, hidden submit button. Just do a `document.getElementById('myform').submit()` or with jQuery `$('#myform').submit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form-any-name">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" class="myButton" />
</form>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button[type=\'submit\']').on('click', function() {
            $("form[id*='form-']").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Simply include document on ready submit catcher you can place that code in main js file since we catching dinamicaly form id starting with form-   so in other pages you can have the different foms:)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post my answer as this post helped me a lot and I came with an idea that works if you want to add the "button outside the form" functionality on older browsers.

I use JQuery but I dont think I would be a major problem to use pure JS as it's not complicated code.

Just create a class just as some of the answers suggested here

```
.hiddenSubmitButton {
    display: none;
}
```

```
$("body").on("click", "button[form]", function () {
    /*This will get the clicks when make on buttons with form attribute
     * it's useful as we commonly use this property  when we place buttons that submit forms outside the form itself
     */
    let form, formProperty, formAttribute, code, newButtonID;
    formProperty = $(this).prop("form");
    if (!(formProperty === null || formProperty === "")) {//Most browsers that don't wsupport form property will return null others "" 
        return; //Browsers that support the form property won't continue
    }
    formAttribute = $(this).attr("form");
    form = $("#" + formAttribute);
    newButtonID = formAttribute + "_hiddenButton";
    if (document.getElementById(newButtonID) !== null) {
        $("#" + newButtonID).click();
        return;
    }
    code = '<input id="' + newButtonID + '" class="hiddenSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />';
    $(form).append(code);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + newButtonID).click();
    }, 50);
});
```

One thing I like about creating buttons outside the form is that they allow us to custom the design more easily and we can use this code and it will work on old browsers and also, the browser will use its HTML form validator.

Answer (score -3):

IE understands 'for', you can use "label for=''".

```
    <label for="form_one_submit">Button one</label>
    <form action="" id="form_one">
      <span></span>
      <input type="submit" id="form_one_submit" style="visibility:hidden;">
    </form>
```

Comment: The question is referring to a button, not a label